# Big Oh Runtime when loop is not of input (n)

Tags: big-o

I was just wondering what the Big O runtime complexity would be for this example?

```
    public void example(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i<32; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

I don't think its O(n) because we don't loop thru n, instead we loop thru 32 times. 
Thanks

Comment: I think this should be in programmers.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a constant time operation, so it is `O(1)` (or `Theta(1)`) as you always perform exactly 32 operations. Although, as `O` notation is just an **upper bound** it is also `O(n)`, `O(lg n)` or even `O(n^n^n^n)`. `O(1)` is just an asymptotically tightest bound for this code. The theta notation gives you exact (bounded from bottom and above) complexity estimation, and as it was said before, this is a `Theta(1)` code as its number of operations is completely independent on the input parameter.